# Open an Excel workbook inside a blank excel workbook using Marshal.GetActiveObject

Tags: c#, interop

I have created a number of unit tests. At the beginning of each test I open a blank excel workbook on the `TestInitialize` however for this particular test I need to open another excel workbook. I want to open it inside the blank workbook opened on the `TestInitialize` . I tried doing the following however it opens them as 2 separate workbooks.

Any ideas why this is happening?

My code is as follows

```
    using xl = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
    private static string columnChartTemp = @"Testing\V8\TestMaster\V8.6\Testing\V8.6.0.11 Testing\columnChart.xlsx";
    var excel = (xl.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
   var myWorkbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(columnChartTemp);
   excel.Visible = true;
```

Comment: are you trying to open a new workbook, or just a new tab?

Comment: @vipersassassin I'm trying to open a workbook

Comment: Then it will always open a separate workbook. If you 'add' it to the current workbook as a tab that would be the only way to keep it in the workbook that was previously opened.

Comment: @vipersassassin this isn't the case when I do it with a word document  `var wordApplication = (word.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application");
            var myDocument = wordApplication.Documents.Open(wordColumnChartTemp);`

Answer (score 0):

A workbook is a file containing one or more worksheets (tabs.) You can't open a workbook inside of another workbook.

It sounds like you want to take a worksheet that's in a workbook and add it to another workbook. You can do that. Open both workbooks and copy the sheet from one to the other.